# Validate time using moment.js

Tags: momentjs

Is there any way to verify just the time part in moment js?

like for date, we have:

```
 moment("2011-10-10", "YYYY-MM-DD").isValid(); // true
```

but `moment("09:00", "HH:mm").isValid();` is not working and always returns true even if the format is invalid.

I am aware of datetime validation but I need to verify time component only. Seems like I will have to go for regex if there isn't anything already there.

```
var formats = ["YYYY-MM-DD LT","YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss A","YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss","YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"];
moment("2014-12-13 12:34 PM", formats, true).isValid()     // true
moment("2014-12-13 15:00", formats, true).isValid()        // true
moment("2014-12-13 12:34:00 PM", formats, true).isValid()  // true
```

Comment: Have you seen the comments on strict parsing https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/

What are your examples where it doesn't work?

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 these are related to formatting dates and validations of date+time, I am looking for just time valiadation without any date.

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 `09:asdasdasd` returns valid

Comment: not with strict on http://jsfiddle.net/oLa2sjhk/4/

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 you probably missed to append isValid() `var ca1a = moment("09:00", "HH:mm")
var ca1b = moment("09:asdasdasd", "HH:mm")` or I am thinking something wrong? you want me to get the values and compare based on that?

Comment: I'll admit I've not named the variables well... tidied up slightly at
http://jsfiddle.net/vszy210c/3/
`ca2` is the most relevant bit. Also to add that my earlier comment was wrong about missing elements.